# Getting ReflectionException while using a Package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-seeding

I am using a [Package](https://github.com/romanbican/roles) for roles and permissions management in my laravel 5.1 application and getting error while trying to create roles by using following code.

```
<?php

use Bican\Roles\Models\Role;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
$adminRole = Role::create([
'name' => 'Admin',
'slug' => 'admin',
'description' => '', // optional
'level' => 1, // optional, set to 1 by default
]);
}
}
```

and I am seeding it using following command on CLI.

```
php artisan db:seed --class=RoleTableSeeder
```

but unfortunately I am getting ReflectionException

> "[ReflectionException] Class RoleTableSeeder does not exist"...

**What might be wrong with it? Looking for your help...**

**Link to Package:** https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the following command on CLI.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**Acknowledged: Package Owner**